# Parsing JSON image urls in iOS error

Tags: ios, json, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to parse a JSON file containing some links to images and some titles and times.

This is my code:

```
#import "PicturesViewController.h"
#import "DemoViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNBlurModalView.h"
#import "PictureJSON.h"
#import "HMSegmentedControl.h"

@interface PicturesViewController ()
{
    NSInteger refreshIndex;
    NSArray *images;
}

@end

@implementation PicturesViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    HMSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[HMSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"Instagram", @"Hashtags", @"Facebook"]];
    [segmentedControl setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 60)];
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlChangedValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    [self issueLoadRequest];
}

- (void)swipeHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [[self sideMenu] showFromPanGesture:sender];
}

- (void)segmentedControlChangedValue:(HMSegmentedControl *)segmentedControl1 {
    [self issueLoadRequest];
}

- (void)segmentedControlSelectedIndexChanged:(id)sender
{
    [self issueLoadRequest];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Button actions

- (void)showMenu
{
    [[self sideMenu] show];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (void)issueLoadRequest
{
    // Dispatch this block asynchronosly. The block gets JSON data from the specified URL and performs the proper selector when done.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my-site/pictureparse.php?name=Name"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // When we have the data, we serialize it into native cocoa objects. (The outermost element from twitter is
    // going to be an array. I JUST KNOW THIS. Reload the tableview once we have the data.
    self.tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PictureJSON";

    PictureJSON *cell = (PictureJSON *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PictureJSON" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // The element in the array is going to be a dictionary. I JUST KNOW THIS. The key for the tweet is "text".
    NSDictionary *tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", [cell class]);
    cell.instaImage = [tweet objectForKey:@"link"];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.timeLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"published"];

    return cell;
}
```

But when I launch my app I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PicturesViewController 0x758bf70> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key instaImage.'
```

My JSON-file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "link": "http://link.com/picture.jpg",
        "title": "title",
        "published": "0:12 PM 21/10"
    },
    {
        "link": "http://link.com/picture.jpg",
        "title": "title",
        "published": "0:09 AM 21/10"
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to check the property instaImage. I think you are accessing the property that you have not defined in nib.

Comment: If cell is not a cell then other two property of the cell should also throw exception.

Answer (score 1):

Fist try to debug this . From the crash log I think  you are doing wrong with the custom cell . first check your connection of the PictureJSON  . and check your file owner it should be your custom cell. You can confirm this using breakpoint . if you get error while cell creation then above is the solution .

Comment: why down vote ? Atleast take some effort to specify the reason .

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with your JSON serialization, from your log this crash because of your     `static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"PictureJSON";`

Make sure, you have assigned your custom cell with this identifier !

Comment: This is not a problem, you can use any string for identifier.

Comment: he is using [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
, if there isn t any cell with this identifier, it will crash